# High memory usage for Pool in for loop

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool

I have a for loop with 2 Pools:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    for length in range(1, 15, 5):

        def map_CCWP(it):
            return CCWP(G, length, Ep)
        pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=multiprocessing.cpu_count())
        Scores = pool.map(map_CCWP, range(R))

        S = []
        # some work to get S

        def map_AvgIAC (it):
            return avgIAC(G, S, Ep, I) 
        pool2 = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=multiprocessing.cpu_count())
        T = pool2.map(map_AvgIAC, range(4))
```

However while running it uses more and more memory, supposedly because it creates new pool workers every time. I tried deleting pools at the end of each iteration but it still increases amount of memory.

Another option was to put pools under condition:

```
if pool == None:
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=multiprocessing.cpu_count())
```

and it indeed doesn't use so much memory. However, every iteration arguments for functions `map_CCWP` and `map_AvgIAC` change and, what I found, `pool.map` will use `map_CCWP` with initial `length` and `map_AvgIAC` with initial `S`.

How can I run Pool on functions that change every iteration and don't increase memory usage?

Answer (score 2):

By default, pool workers are created at the beginning and live to the end. You are not initialising them, so there is no big performance advantage to keep them alive in your case.

So:

```
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=None, maxtasksperchild=1)
```

will create a worker, run the process, kill it, and create a new worker. Any memory or resources caught will be freed. If your memory growth is not too big, you can increase the number of tasks per child.

Note that I define processes as `None`. This is the same as using `multiprocessing.cpu_count()`, but less verbose.

On other situation, I encountered that sometimes (once or twice in millions), the memory of a random child will grow out of control, the machine will start swapping, and everything gets stuck or very slowed down. My workaround was this:

```
iterations = int(math.ceil(total / b_size))

for block in xrange(iterations):
    restricted_iterator = iterator[block * b_size:(block + 1) * b_size]
    # This works because a slice can end beyond the length of the list.

    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=None, maxtasksperchild=1)
    try:
        peaks = pool.map(caller, restricted_iterator)
    except Exception as e:
        raise e    # I don't expect this to ever happen.
    finally:
        pool.terminate()
                   # Kill the pool very dead.
    # Save the data to disk and free memory.
```

I split the work in chunks, and process each one. This way, if there is ever one of this "crazy children" accumulating memory, the rest will finish in a few minutes, the stray child will be alone for some time, having more RAM available. As a consequence, it will finish in less than a couple of minutes, so the total delay of the program is not so big. By tuning `b_size` I can control how often I am cleaning up. (In my case, splitting in 10-20 blocks, and saving to disk in the middle, I still keep the average CPU usage around 97%, so not much is lost).

Comment: Let discuss the first part of your answer. Should I use `pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=None, maxtasksperchild=1)` without any condition I described? Should I somehow free the memory at the end of each iteration? Right now I still observe increase in memory after each iteration.

Comment: Using that line will ensure no Python objects are left cluttering your memory, which should take you most of the way. You should also `terminate` the pool once it is finished, to be sure. It could be that `CCWP` has a memory leak, you could check it by running without the pool repeatedly. The problem could also be that the output is itself big, so the memory has to grow. I don't see how using a condition is going to help.

Comment: About `CCWP` leakage. You mean just to use `map` instead of `pool.map`? I still have increase of memory in this case, although not as big. With `pool.map` I have 2.3Gb, without I have 1.8Gb. About output is big. After each iteration I just want know `T` that is just an integer. Everything else can be freed. Should I still expect increase of memory in this case?

Comment: So, CCWP is leaking 500 MB due to multiprocessing and 1.8 GB by itself. Fix CCWP first and then worry about the 500 MB (unless the 1.8 GB are the data output). `T` cannot be an integer, as you show it, it is a list with four elements. You can `del` big objects when you stop using them, and wrapping each iteration in a function will do that for you at the end; something like: `compute_T(length) for length in...`

Comment: Wait.. but I have 1.3Gb used even before I start running everything. While running it can go up to the whole memory usage (~5Gb). About T. You're right: T is a list, I then take a norm of it and get a number. In any case, I use `map_CCWP`, `Scores`, `S`, `pool` at each iteration, but they're different for all iterations. So once I used them I don't need them; but I overwrite them and thought it will use the same amount of memory each iteration. Isn't it the case?

Comment: Yes, they should be completely overwritten, but if you may get bitten by some cyclic references.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are creating more and more pools during your program life time. What if you initialize one fixed size pool before the for loop, and then your for loop only adds task into that pool? That way, conceptually your parallel processes are limited by the pool size, so memory consumption should be under control.